# Set up a pipe to a program as virtual Alsa speaker

Tags: alsa

I have a program that takes an audio pipe and broadcasts it as FM radio. My question is if I can somehow set it up as an   alsa speaker so all audio is redirected to it.

The common usage of it is:

```
*command that send wave audio to stdout* | ./PiFMPlay PIPE 87.7
```

Comment: The [file plugin](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm_plugins.html#pcm_plugins_file) can output to a pipe.